# How to call async.each in an external function having async.waterfall inside async.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, mongoose

I have a exports module in Node.JS

```
exports.doSomethingImportant= function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
Demo.findOne({'_id': id})
  .exec(function(err, demosReturned) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(outerCallBack){
          console.log("In the First Call Back");
          firstOrderFunction(demosReturned,outerCallBack);
        },
        function(x,outerCallBack){
           var y =3 
           var z = x*y;
           console.log("In the Second Call Back");
           outerCallBack(null,z);
        }
      ],function(err,z){
        if(err){
          console.log("Error is == " +err);
        }else{
          console.log("The Returned Value is == "+z);
        }
      });
});//End Demo.findOne
};
```

Now, my `firstOrderfunction` again has a `async.each` embedding `async.waterfall`

```
function fistOrderFunction(demosReturned,outerCallBack){
console.log("Called the External Function");


async.each(demosReturned.locations, function(location, innerCallBack) {
  console.log('Computing Location #');

    async.waterfall([
          function(internalCallBack){
             console.log("Computing Inner First Waterfall");
               a = 14;
              innternalCallBack(null,a);
          },
          function(a,internalCallBack){
              console.log("Computing Inner Second Waterfall");
               b =14;
               c = a*b;
              innternalBack(null,c)
          }
      ],function(err,c){
        if(err){
          console.log("Error is == " +err);
        }else{
             d = c;
             console.log("The Returned Value is == "+c);
             innerCallBack(null,d);
        }
    });//End Async.Waterfall
},function(err,d){
    if(err){enter code here
      console.log("The Error in Async.Each === " + err);
    }else{
      console.log("The Returned Value is Processed ");
      outerCallBack(null, d);
    }
}); //End Async.Each
}
```

The Output I get is

---

> In the First Call Back
>
> Called the External Function
>
> Computing Location #
>
> Computing Location #
>
> Computing Inner First Waterfall
>
> Computing Inner First Waterfall
>
> The Returned Value is Processed
>
> In the Second Call Back
>
> The Returned Value is == NaN

I want everything to be run synchronously in the following order.

> 1. Call async.waterfall in exec call back of Demo.findone
> 2. Call the firstOrderFunction
> 3. Call async.each inside firstOrderFunction
> 4. Call async.waterfall inside async.each
> 5. Call the first callback function returning a=14.
> 6. Call the second callback function returning c =14*14 =196.

How do I achieve this using async?

Thanks in advance and apology for such a long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call async.each()'s callback at the end of async.waterfall() and call firstOrderFunction's callback at the end of async.each().  Here is the revised code:

```
function fistOrderFunction(demosReturned, callback){
  var ret = [];

  console.log("Called the External Function");
  async.each(demosReturned.locations, function(location, eachCb) {
    console.log('Computing Location #');

    async.waterfall([
        function(waterfallCb){
            console.log("Computing Inner First Waterfall");
            a = 14;
            waterfallCb(null,a);
        },
        function(a,waterfallCb){
            console.log("Computing Inner Second Waterfall");
            b =14;
            c = a*b;
            waterfallCb(null,c)
        }
    ],function(err,c){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error is == " +err);
            eachCb(err);
        }else{
            ret.push(c);
            console.log("The Returned Value is == "+c);
            eachCb(null);
        }
    });//End Async.Waterfall
  },function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("The Error in Async.Each === " + err);
        callback(err, null);
    }else{
        console.log("The Returned Value is Processed ");
        callback(null, ret);
    }
  }); //End Async.Each
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. I was trying to pass `ret` to the `async.each` callback. So `ret` was out of scope there as `async.waterfall` had already finished executing. Much Thanks. Cheers! :)